# How to create this gradient background in CSS3?

Tags: css, gradient, background-color

I used the following image as the background throughout [my site](https://skitch.com/keruilin/rwcsq/winthetrophy-the-new-way-to-bet-sports-free-sports-betting-free-nfl-betting).

[image]

How can you use CSS3 and gradients to produce a similar visual element?

Comment: It's very, very hard to see the colors you used to form that gradient against this site's white background. Could you tell us the colors you used?

Comment: Aaand you still haven't revealed the colours? It would be a help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't really see that small image, but I advise you to try an online CSS3 generator, like this one:

[CSS3 Gradient Generator](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the code that you are looking for CSS.**

**~~ HTML ~~**

```
<DIV class="mygradient"></DIV>
```

**~~ CSS ~~**

```
.mygradient{

    height:300px;
    width:100px;

    background: #7a0000; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #7a0000 0%, #900000 63%, #940000 96%, #650000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#7a0000), color-stop(63%,#900000), color-stop(96%,#940000), color-stop(100%,#650000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #7a0000 0%,#900000 63%,#940000 96%,#650000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #7a0000 0%,#900000 63%,#940000 96%,#650000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #7a0000 0%,#900000 63%,#940000 96%,#650000 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #7a0000 0%,#900000 63%,#940000 96%,#650000 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7a0000', endColorstr='#650000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}
```

*Add a "gradient" class to all your elements that have a gradient for IE9 support.*

**~~ HTML ~~**

```
<DIV class="mygradient gradient"></DIV>
```

*and also add the following override to your HTML to complete the IE9 support:*

**~~ HTML ~~** *FOR IE9 FULL SUPPORT*

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    .gradient {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSS3](http://css3please.com/) provides a more cross-browser way of doing it.

Example

```
.box_gradient {  
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ddd);
  /* FF3.6 */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ddd);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ddd);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ddd);  
  /* IE6–IE9 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#dddddd');
}
```

You will need to 100% height your html and body tags.